# urlSlugify on FreeCodeCamp not passing tests when it should

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling to pass something that seems simple enough on FreeCodeCamp. My code should pass all the tests (console.log seems to think so). What do you think, am I missing something?

Test case I'm failing:

```
urlSlug(" Winter Is  Coming") should return "winter-is-coming".
```

My console.log:

```
winter-is-coming
```

My Code:

```
// the global variable
var globalTitle = "Winter Is Coming";

// Add your code below this line
function urlSlug(title) {
    return title.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).join("-");
}
// Add your code above this line

var winterComing = urlSlug(globalTitle); // Should be "winter-is-coming"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> urlSlug(" Winter Is  Coming") should return "winter-is-coming".

This statement is wrong due to your function :

```
function urlSlug(title) {
    return title.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).join("-");
}
```

It will replace all spaces with slash, including the first space. To pass the test you should add trim() to the function as this:

```
function urlSlug(title) {
    return title.trim().toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).join("-");
}
```

Run the code snippet to see the results:

```js
// the global variable
var globalTitle = "Winter Is Coming";

// Add your code below this line
function urlSlug(title) {
    return title.trim().toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).join("-");
}
// Add your code above this line

var winterComing = urlSlug(globalTitle);

console.log(winterComing);
console.log(urlSlug(" Winter Is  Coming"));
```

Comment: This is great- I had started using .trim but thought I was on the wrong track. Thanks.